# How long will a CR2032 battery take to exhaust powering two 5mm blue LEDs

Tags: voltage, led

I read on the Internet that a typical coin cell battery has an ampere hour of 225mAh. I connected up a CR2032 battery to two blue LEDs and left it switched on expecting it to take approximately 5 and 1/2 hours before the battery was exhausted, but 9 and 1/2 hours later the LEDs are still glowing brightly. How long should it take before the battery is dead? Is there a reliable way to calculate this?

Comment: Did you measure the *current* consumed by the blue LED's?? BTW, they're *very* efficient, even at low currents. In a dark room, I can see a glow at 500 pA or less!

Comment: The battery mAh rating would depend on the current drawn from it. One CR2032 battery datasheet says it has 235 mAh with 15kohm load, or 0.19mA, and will run for 1245 hours. If you don't know the current that is drawn by the LEDs, you have no way of estimating how long the battery lasts.

Comment: In addition to the excellent comments so far, there's little guarantee about the most you can get from a battery. Just a few "typical" cases you can use to estimate, rather vaguely, what to expect. Also, while the self-discharge is very low, it's possible that the age of the batteries you get could have some impact. I only mean this in terms of making quantitative predictions that are also accurate predictions. However, you can research this yourself!! That's the cool thing. Monitor the voltage across your LEDs, the current through them over time, and let us know what you find out!

Comment: I didn't measure the current draw from the LEDs, I assumed the actual draw would be around 20mA per LED.

Comment: Don't assume! Measure! You want a "reliable way to calculate?" Then measure!!

Comment: Why did you think the LEDs would draw 20mA each? The 3.0V battery has barely enough voltage to reach the rated forward voltage of a typical blue led. Let me guess, you are also not using resistors?

Comment: I can't measure the current because the LEDs are soldered into a PCB and I have no other LEDs. I guess I will leave the circuit powered on until the glow dies and use that as a measure of time.

Comment: I thought the LEDs would draw 20mA each because that's what I read a typical LED consumes. The LEDs came as part of a kit that recommended it be powered by a coincell CR2032 battery.

Comment: *because that's what I read a typical LED consumes* LEDs don't work that way, a LED will "take all the current you give it" provided you apply enough voltage across the LED. Note that too much current will **destroy** the LED. The 20 mA is a **recommended operating current**. So there needs to be a **series resistor** to make sure the LED can take no more than 20 mA. A CR2032 has some series resistance and that can work as well. But that's not "proper engineering", even though it does work. But you're stressing both LED and CR2032.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie neither are being stressed... 4mA at 3V won't blow the led or cause the battery to fail.

Comment: The easiest way to determine this is going to be to test it with a few batteries and different blue LEDs. It's not easy to predict accurately because the internal resistance  of the battery and the voltage-current relationship of the LED is not well specified, and (perhaps more importantly) the end-of-life brightness is pretty subjective (since the human eye has a log response).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2 blue leds, so typically 3.2~3.6V forward voltage drop at 20mA forward current, will run at a much lower current when the voltage across them are less than that typical forward voltage.

They are likely to be running at 5mA or less, when the CR2032 is fully charged at 3.2V. From a random blue led data sheet http://descargas.cetronic.es/WW05A3SBQ4-N.pdf:

[image]

And a current vs capacity graph of a CR2032 https://www.ept.ca/features/designing-sensor-based-iot-devices-coin-cell-batteries/:

[image]

As the available voltage drops, the leds use less current, so they last longer too. It's like a see-saw where the led current and the battery voltage kinda level themselves out nicely. So between you not calculating the correct current drawn, and the curve of both the led and battery, the actual lifetime of the setup will be much longer than a general formula of (Battery Capacity in mAh / current draw) would tell you.

Leds do not have to run at their normal max current. That's just when they are their brightest. But they are still bright at lower voltages/currents.

Answer (score -1):

Calculating how much a battery can run a load depends on the load current. If you measure the current, you can then approximate the time until battery is depleted, by using typical ratings from datasheets.